# Rewinding techniques with some examples

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation

I'm aware of these posts:

[What is a "rewinding argument"?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/what-is-a-rewinding-argument/3817#3817)

[Random oracle model proofs and programmability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/random-oracle-model-proofs-and-programmability/1412#1412)

But I think, some concrete examples are missing.

---

I need to know how exactly rewinding technique is used with some examples.

Moreover, I'd like to know how many time we need to rewind a party and in the case where we consider a semi-honest adversary, the adversary's random value is fixed no matter how many times we rewind it.