# Could any one suggest alternative Zero knowledge proof protocol to Schnorr protocol ZKP?

Tags: public-key, cryptanalysis, zero-knowledge-proofs, schnorr-identification

I read that Schnorr protocol cannot be proved zero knowledge on that link:

[Perfect zero knowledge for the Schnorr protocol?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/perfect-zero-knowledge-for-the-schnorr-protocol)
Could any one suggest alternative Zero knowledge proof protocol so a prover can prove to **a verifier that he knows the private key corresponding to a particular public key?**

Comment: Does the verifier sending a message encrypted with the prover's public key using Elgamal encryption and the prover being able to decrypt the message count?

Comment: Technically no, that would not be zero-knowledge. Heba Mohsen, are you asking for a modification of Schnorr protocol that makes it really zero-knowledge?