# Random oracles and the Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: provable-security, random-oracle-model

I am trying to understand the implication of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma to the random oracle model.

I think understanding a special case, say, a random oracle is one-way with probability 1, would be helpful. The statement (see, e.g., page 19 of Arkady Yerukhimovich's [thesis](https://www2.seas.gwu.edu/%7Earkady/papers/thesis.pdf)) as far as I understand in words goes like "if the adversary $A$ given access to an $n$-bit random oracle $O_n$ succeeds in the game (given $y$, output a preimage $x\in O^{-1}(y)$) with probability at most $1/n^2$, then $A$ must fail the game for sufficiently large $n$ with probability 1 over choices of $O$."

I don't understand what it means by "with probability 1 over choices of $O$," when $O$ does not refer to a specific size $n$ (which I think is the setting where the Borel-Cantelli Lemma applies). The adversary $A$ is uniform, and therefore the adversary $A_n$ for $n$-bit oracle can be constructed by learning the size of $O$.

Let the distribution $D_n$ be the uniform distribution over $n$-bit functions. Clearly $D_n$ is the distribution of an $n$-bit random oracle. But I suspect that the same statement works for other distribution (i.e., whether the oracle distribution is uniform or not does not matter).

Does the statement mean that for $D=D_1\times D_2\times\ldots$ and a sequence of oracles $O_1,O_2,...$ sampled from $D$, $A_1,A_2...$ must fail the game for sufficiently large $n$ with probability $1$ over choices $O_1,O_2,...$? If that's correct, then I'm not sure if $D$ is well-defined. If not, I'd appreciate if you could let me know precisely what the correct statement is.

Comment: Borel cantelli lemma is hardly a standard cryptography tool. You can improve your question by stating it. Also, does it not apply to infinite sequence of RVs?

Comment: Thanks. I improved the question. I suspect it applies but I'm not sure.

Comment: "I don't understand what it means by "with probability 1 over choices of $O$," when $O$ does not refer to a specific size $n$". Since the number of possible $O=\{O_1,O_2,\cdots\}$ is uncountable, we have to rely on measure theory. So, that statement should really be "for *measure* 1 of $O$s". There is a one-to-one correspondence between random (bit) oracles and reals: choose a random real $r$ and then the set the value of $O(x)$ as $r_i$, the $x$-th bit of $r$. So, it boils down to defining measure for reals, which you can find in standard textbooks. Does this clear your doubt?

Comment: @ckamath I think my confusion is that whether the Borel-Cantelli lemma really means A wins the game with probability/measure 0 over $O_1,O_2,\ldots$. And my interpretation of your answer seems to suggest it is correct. And thanks for clarifying on whether the distribution over $O_1,O_2,\ldots$ can be made well-defined, though I still don't get what it means by choosing a random real.

Comment: "... whether the Borel-Cantelli lemma really means A wins the game with probability/measure 0 over..". It's subtle. It is used to show that only for measure $0$ of $O$s the adversary's advantage is more than expected at infinitely-many $n$s. In other other words, for measure $1$ of $O$s, the adversary's advantage is more than expected at only finitely-many $n$s. This can now be used to argue that for measure $1$ of $O$s, the adversary's advantage is negligible.

Comment: "I still don't get what it means by choosing a random real." For this, one has to first define a probability measure on $(0,1]$ via Borel sets and Lebesgue measure. You can read more about it in [this lecture note](https://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~krishnaj/EE5110_files/notes/lecture7_Borel%20Sets%20and%20Lebesgue%20Measure.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\AA}{\mathsf{A}}
\newcommand{\sO}{\mathcal{O}}
\newcommand{\fO}{O}
\newcommand{\str}{\{0,1\}^*}
\newcommand{\strn}{\{0,1\}^n}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\adv}{\varepsilon_{\AA,\fO}}
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\SUCCESS}{\text{SUCCESS}_{\AA,\fO,x}}
\newcommand{\DEVIATION}{\text{DEVIATION}_{\AA,\fO,n}}
$

Let's go through the proof from [Y,IR] in a bit more detail since it is technical and subtle (I struggled a lot with it). The role of [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) will become clear in the process, and is summarised at the end.

*Random oracles.* We consider (function) oracles $\fO:\str\to\str$ interpreted as an ensemble of oracles $\{O_1,O_2,\cdots\}$, where $\fO_n:\strn\to\strn$.
Let $\sO$, denote the set of all such oracles.
Since $|\sO|$ is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set), before talking about [random oracles](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/80502/11441), we need to define what it means to randomly sample from a sample space that is uncountable.
To this end, one defines a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)).
Since there is a one-to-one correspondence$^*$ between $\sO$ and $[0,1)$, one can resort to Borel sets and Lebesgue measure: see [this](https://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/%7Ekrishnaj/EE5110_files/notes/lecture7_Borel%20Sets%20and%20Lebesgue%20Measure.pdf) lecture note for more details.

*Random oracles are one-way.* Now, our goal is to show that random oracles are one-way in a very strong sense: for measure $1$ of random oracles $\fO$, $\fO$ is a one-way function (OWF), i.e.,
$$
\Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\forall\AA\in\text{PPT}:\adv(\cdot)\text{ is negligible}]=1,
$$
where the advantage $\adv(\cdot)$ is defined as
$$
\adv(n):=\Pr_{\AA,x\leftarrow\strn}[\underbrace{\AA(\fO(x))\in\fO^{-1}(O(x))}_{\text{Event }\SUCCESS}],
$$
and it is [negligible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function) if
$$
\forall c\in\NN~\exists n_c\in\NN~\forall n>n_c:\adv(n)\geq1/n^c.
$$
We proceed as follows.

1. Let's first analyse the advantage with respect to a *fixed adversary and input*.
   It can be shown by lazy sampling$^{**}$ that
   $$
   \forall\AA\in\text{PPT}~\forall n\in\NN~\forall x\in\strn:\Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\SUCCESS]\leq n^a/2^n,
   $$
   where, for $a\in\NN$ (which depends on $\AA$), $n^a$ is the upper bound on $\AA$'s runtime.
2. Next, we bound the probability that $\AA$ *deviates from expected behaviour*.
   To this end, let's define a bad event
   $$
   \DEVIATION:\adv(n)> n^{a+2}/2^n.
   $$
   It can be shown by applying [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)$^{**}$ that
   $$
   \forall\AA\in\text{PPT}\forall n\in\NN:\Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\DEVIATION]\leq1/n^2.
   $$
3. We are now ready to apply Borel-Cantelli lemma.
   Since
   $$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty\Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\DEVIATION]\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty1/n^2<\infty,
   $$
   by Borel-Cantelli lemma, we get that
   $$
   \forall\AA\in\text{PPT}:\Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\DEVIATION \text{ occurs for infinitely-many } n \text{s}]=0.
   $$
4. This means for each adversary $\AA$, we can fix a measure $0$ of "bad" oracles $\sO^*_\AA\subseteq\sO$.
   Since the number of PPT Turing machines is countable (but infinite) and union of countable measure $0$ oracles is still measure $0$, we get that the set of all bad oracles $\sO^*=\cup_\AA\sO^*_\AA\subseteq\sO$ is still measure $0$.
   Therefore, we can *switch the order of the quantifiers* to get:
   $$
   \Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\forall\AA\in\text{PPT}:\DEVIATION \text{ occurs for infinitely-many } n \text{s}]=0.
   $$
5. Finally, let's establish one-wayness.
   The above equation is equivalent to
   $$
   \Pr_{\fO\leftarrow\sO}[\forall\AA\in\text{PPT}:\adv(n)>n^{a+2}/2^n \text{ for finitely-many } n \text{s}]=1.
   $$
   It follows that there exists a $n_\AA\in\NN$ such that $\forall n>n_\AA,\adv(n)\leq n^{a+2}/2^n$.
   Since $n^{a+2}/2^n$ is a negligible function, and $\adv(n)$ grows slower than $n^{a+2}/2^n$ for all $n>n_\AA$, it follows that $\adv(n)$ is also negligible, which completes the proof.

*To sum up, the Borel-Cantelli lemma is used to show that the bad event, $\DEVIATION$, **does not** occur [infinitely-often](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512810/definition-about-infinitely-often), which then implies that it does not occur after a sufficiently large $n$, just like in the definition of negligible. This is key to establishing that the advantage is negligible.*

$^*$This correspondence is easy to see for bit oracles: given a real number $r=0.r_0r_1\cdots\in[0,1)$, simply set the output $O(x)$ as $r_x$, the $x$-th bit of $r$. This can be extended to the function oracles as shown in [IR].

$^{**}$ See [IR,Y] for details.

[IR]: Impagliazzo and Rudich, *[Limits on the Provable Consequences of One-Way Permutations](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Erussell/secret.ps)*. STOC 1989.

[Y]: Yerukhimovich, *[A Study of Separations in Cryptography: New Results and Models](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/handle/1903/12199)*, 2011, PhD Thesis