# Why is H(message||secret_key) not vulnerable to length-extension attack?

Tags: hash, mac, length-extension, merkle-damgaard

Given a Merkle-Damgård hash function $H$, [I know](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/understanding-a-length-extension-attack/3979#3979) that an attacker can forge a message protected by a MAC computed as $H(\textrm{secret_key}||\textrm{message})$.

Why can't he perform the same extension attack on a MAC construction $H(\textrm{message}||\textrm{secret_key})$?

Comment: You can perform a length extension, but then the message doesn't end with the secret key anymore and is thus not a valid authentication tag.

Comment: Regardless, you should almost certainly be [using an HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Comment: Related: [Attacks of the MAC construction H(m||k) for common hashes H?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/attacks-of-the-mac-construction-mathcalhmk-for-common-hashes-mathcal)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### How does the [length extension attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/understanding-a-length-extension-attack) against $H(k||m)$ work?

For Merkle-Damgård hashes, if you know $H(x)$ but not $x$ you can still choose an $e$ and then compute $H(x||p||e)$. With $x=k||m$ you can compute $H((k||m||p)||e)=H(k||(m||p||e))$ which is a valid authentication tag for $m||p||e$.

### Why doesn't it work against $H(m||k)$?

With a length extension an attacker chooses the extension. The only non trivial way to make $H(m||k||e)$ a valid tag is if $e$ ends with $k$. Since the attacker doesn't know the secret key they can't put the key at the end of $e$ and thus can't produce a valid tag.

### What should I be using?

Either use H(k||m) with a hash that's not vulnerable to length extension attacks, such SHA3. Or use HMAC with  an older hashfunction, such as SHA2. $H(m||k)$ is not ideal because it can be [attacked by finding collisions of $H$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/attacks-of-the-mac-construction-mathcalhmk-for-common-hashes-mathcal). Collisions are one of the easier attacks crypto-analytically and require a hashfunction twice the width of the target security level. e.g. SHA-256 for a 128 bit security level.