# Can I compute “SHA256(secret||data)” when having “SHA256(secret)” and “data”?

Tags: cryptanalysis, sha-256, length-extension

I need to find the SHA256 hash of s string like this: `part1-part2`. I know the SHA256(part1), length of `part1` and I know `part2`, but I don't know what is the contents of `part1`.

Is there any chance I can compute the hash of the whole string using only these three parts of information?

Comment: You can compute $\operatorname{SHA256}(\mathit{secret}\Vert\mathit{padding}\Vert\mathit{data})$ using a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), but computing $\operatorname{SHA256}(\mathit{secret}\Vert\mathit{data})$ for freely chosen $\mathit{data}$ without the $\mathit{padding}$ in between is assumed to be hard (i.e. practically impossible, unless SHA256 turns out to be severely broken). [HashPump](https://github.com/bwall/HashPump) is a tool to perform length extensions.

Comment: I understand. This attack is not suitable for what I am looking for, as it doesn't give me the exact SHA256(secret||data). Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@yyyyyy already commented](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/find-sha256secretdata-using-sha256secret-and-data?rq=1#comment81215_34795): if you are able to successfully apply a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), you would be able to compute

$$\operatorname{SHA256}(\mathit{secret}\Vert\mathit{padding}\Vert\mathit{data})$$

But computing $\operatorname{SHA256}(\mathit{secret}\Vert\mathit{data})$ for freely chosen $\mathit{data}$ without the $\mathit{padding}$ in between is assumed to be “hard”; meaning that you’ll end up having to brute-force your way towards a result.

Also see “[understanding a length extension attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/understanding-a-length-extension-attack)” for a more indeep understanding of things.