# Is hashing random numbers generated from a TRNG enough to create a key?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator

Is hashing random numbers generated from a TRNG enough to create a key?

Basically taking the output of something like a [Lavarand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavarand) and pass that through a hash function like sha-2.

I guess at the end of the day the core of my question is, can an hash function be used as a pseudorandom number generator?

Comment: We had recently a question about this and many. All questions are welcomed and searched questions are more accepted by the community. [How to calculate the bias of cryptographic hash output from biased input?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55657/18298) [Using a Hash as a secure PRNG](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9076/18298)

Comment: Just a little quirk re. terminology, but output from a decent TRNG can be used for keys as is. Lava lamps are just a entropy source, not a TRNG per se.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you have a TRNG you can use the output from it when a random key is required for cryptographic purposes.

If you doubt your TRNG indeed has sufficient entropy and sufficiently small bias, a good strategy is to collect more bits than needed from your entropy source and hash them using a secure hash algorithm.

I believe Lavarand already does something similar it collects entropy and uses it to seed a PRNG. I did not actually review the internal so can't comment but if they do a reasonable job hashing the output would be redundant.