# Why is Boneh-Franklin IBE scheme secure? What should an adversary do to break it?

Tags: identity-based-encryption

Even after reading [their paper](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/bfibe.pdf) I am still not able to understand why the scheme is secure and what an adversary should do to break it. This question might look stupid to most of you but I don't have mathematics background to delve this deep into cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed scheme is IND-ID-CPA secure and is [semantically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantically_secure) in a random-oracle model.

From the paper:

> The proof of security for our IBE system makes
> use of a weaker notion of security known as semantic security (also known as semantic security against
> a chosen plaintext attack). Semantic security is similar to chosen ciphertext security (IND-IDCCA) except that the adversary is more limited;

And detailing IND-ID-CPA:

> We say that an identity-based encryption scheme $E$ is semantically
> secure (IND-ID-CPA) if no polynomially bounded adversary $A$ has a non-negligible advantage against
> the Challenger in the following IND-ID-CPA game:

The paper then goes into detail (which I suppose you've read).  But basically the game involves the adversary not being able to better than guess the value of an encrypted bit for a chosen public key.  The adversary has access as to as many other public/private keys as it wants.

The scheme is not [IND-CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack/adaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_(IND-CCA1,_IND-CCA2)) secure.  As per this answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32221/why-boneh-franklin-basicident-ibe-is-not-chosen-ciphertext-secure-why-use-rando) one way to attack the scheme would be to gain access to a "decryption oracle".