# Encoding an element in $r=r'||h(r')$ way

Tags: hash, protocol-design, collision-resistance, protocol-analysis

We consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime e.g. 256-bit.

We have $b$ a fixed element of the field. We encode it as $b'=b||h(b)$, where $h(.)$ is a cryptographic hash function. Assume the output of $h(.)$ is of size 160-bit.
We encode that way to distinguish the element $b'$ from a random element $r$ of the field.

So to check if the element has the above structure we do:

(1) Parse the value: $r=r'||r''$, where size of $r''$ is 160-bit.

(2) check: $h(r')\stackrel{?}=r''$

---

**Question1:** How can we show/prove that the random element only with a negligible probability can have such structure?

**Question2:** Can we reduce the $h(.)$ output size to 80-bit (which is not the standard hash function output size) and set $p$ as smaller prime number (e.g. 128-bit )and prove a random value can have the above structure with only negligible probability?

Citing a paper that use/prove such statement would suffice.

Comment: Is a proof in the [random oracle model](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/879/what-is-the-random-oracle-model-and-why-is-it-controversial) sufficient? If so, the proofs seem pretty simple.

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, please. I can start with that.

Comment: I'm confused, your value $b'$ is 416 bits long. A random field element $r$ will be only 256 bits long.

Comment: @mikeazo Let me make the output of h(.) of size 80-bit everywhere.

Comment: Never mind. I think I understand now. You pick some $r'$, such that $r'||h(r')$ is 256 bits. So if the output of $h$ is 160 bits, then $r'$ is 96 bits long. If the output of $h$ is 80 bits, then $r'$ is 176 bits.

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, Sorry I was talking with my colleague. You're right. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question1: How can we show/prove that the random element only with a negligible probability can have such structure?

If we assume the [random oracle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) and have $h: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^n$ then we can state that $h(.)$ is equivalent to randomly sampling from $\{0,1\}^n$. Thus for a random element $r = r'||r''$ the probability that $r$ has the structure $r'' = h(r')$ is $\frac{1}{2^n}$ since all $2^n$ possible outputs of $h(r')$ are equally likely. Thus for $n=160$ we have a probability of $\frac{1}{2^{160}}$ which is negligible.

> Question2: Can we reduce the $h(.)$ output size to 80-bit (which is not the standard hash function output size) and set $p$ as smaller prime number (e.g. 128-bit )and prove a random value can have the above structure with only negligible probability?

Sure, the same logic as above can be applied here as well, now with the case $n=80$ and a corresponding probability of $\frac{1}{2^{80}}$ which is still negligible.

Note that the size of $r'$ is not relevant to the probability of a random element having the structure $r'||h(r')$, the probability solely depends on the size of $h(r')$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have another question, if you don't mind.: What if value $r$ is not a uniformly random element of the field. In other words, can the answer apply to the case where $r$ is a fixed value.

Comment: Sure, we can choose any element $r \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and this inequality holds.

Comment: Do we also need to take the collision probability into account? I mean, what would happen if two elements have the same hash value.

Comment: I fail to see how collision probability applies. Even if other elements have the same hash as $r'$ this doesn't change the probability of a randomly sampled value $r'||r''$ having $r'' = h(r')$.