# Why is a HMAC using a 32bit tag not prone to birthday attacks?

Tags: authentication, hmac, mac, birthday-attack

Why is a HMAC using a 32bit tag not prone to birthday attacks?

I have read that it has something to do with the fact a birthday attack isn't really possible if the *output size is not large enough*. But then that asks the question of at what size does it become valid and a practical attack can be carried out?

If it isn't prone to birthday attack then what would be the probability of guessing a valid tag value for something as weak as a 32 bits in length?

Probability of a single hash collision$$\frac{1}{2^{32}}$$

**However** the birthday paradox mathematically suggests that this probability should be n^32/2...

Or am I missing something here?

**Update:** The goal of the attack is just guess what the tag might be.

Comment: What would be the attacker's goal be? In the most permissive attack model for a MAC, the attacker has an oracle that can compute tags for an arbitrary number of messages of his choosing, and he is  then challenged to produce any valid message+tag pair where he _hasn't_ asked the oracle about that particular message yet. Finding a tag collision doesn't seem to help him with this task at all.

Comment: The attackers goal is to correctly guess what the computed tag would be. It's simply asking what is the probability that an adversary could guess a random value from a 32bit tag and be correct.

Comment: x @NoDirection, but what is the "birthday attack" you're speaking about? As far as I'm aware, "birthday" in crypto-ish contexts is about collissions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm see here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZovSCFZffM

Comment: Yes its about collisions, the question is what is the probability of having one of the those collisions.

Comment: Hope my updated message explains this better.

Comment: x @NoDirection: Again, even if you find two messages that you now know have the same tag, this should in no way help you guessing the tag of a message you _haven't_ shown to your oracle.

Comment: The birthday paradox says that after you shift through about $2^{32/2}$ messages, it is likely that among the messages you have seen there will be two that have the same tag. How does that help you attack the MAC?

Comment: If two outputs match then an attacker can take their tag and hash a new message of their own and impostor as the sender. The recipient receives the same MAC and thinks the message is authentic.

Comment: Your task as an attacker is to find or guess the correct tag _for a message that you haven't shown to the oracle_. Once you know that two messages have the same tag, both of these messages are off-limits as answers to the challenge.

Comment: So you are saying that the birthday attack has no effect here as the attacker has no list of previous tags to compare against anyway? The probability therefore is just 1/32^2 ?

Comment: The attacker (in the model I sketched, which I believe is the most attacker-friendly model for breaking a MAC) can ask for the correct tags for as many messages as he wants, but then he needs to guess the tag for _something he has not asked about yet_. Discovering a tag collision among the messages he _has_ asked about will not help him do that ... unless you can see something I can't, in which case I invite you to explain further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Birthday attacks" relate to the mathematical phenomenon colloquially known as the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), which states that if you generate random value in a space of size $N$, you expect to hit your first collision, i.e. generating a value that you already generated previously, after having produced about $\sqrt{N}$ values. This can lead to actual *attacks* in some contexts. It so happens that the normal usage context of HMAC is *not* one of these contexts.

HMAC is about *checked integrity*: it is a keyed function that is computed over a given message. In the most generic model, the attacker is allowed to submit $n$ messages $m_i$ of his own choice, and obtain the corresponding HMAC value $h_i$; and his goal is to achieve a *forgery*, i.e. a new message $m$ distinct from all submitted $m_i$, and the corresponding HMAC value $h$.

HMAC being what it is, it operates as a [random oracle](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/879/what-is-the-random-oracle-model-and-why-is-it-controversial/880#880): from the point of view of the attacker, every time he submits a new message $m_i$, the obtained HMAC value $h_i$ is indistinguishable from a newly generated random value. Thus, when considering an as yet unsubmitted message $m$, the attacker's chances at predicting the HMAC value are essentially $1/2^r$, where $r$ is the length (in bits) of the HMAC output. In your case, $r = 32$, so anytime the attacker tries to predict the HMAC output for a message, then either he already submitted that exact message, and thus he can predict with probability $1$, or he did *not* submit that exact message previously, so his prediction will be true with probability $2^{-32}$ only.

The birthday problem, here, says that once the attacker has observed (or submitted) more than about $2^{16}$ messages, he can expect *collisions*, i.e. two distinct messages that map to the same HMAC value. But this does not change anything for the attacker, in that he still has no clue about what will be the next HMAC value for any given (new) message.

In fact, one can say that the birthday problem really incarnates how much collisions do *not* help the attacker. If you imagine a MAC system that takes care never to produce the same MAC value as previously (e.g. by remembering all produced MAC values in a database), then, message after message, the space of remaining possible MAC values get thinner. Ultimately, with such a system, once $2^{32}-1$ message+MAC have been obtained, the attacker could predict the next MAC value with probability $1$, since that would be the only MAC value not produced yet. But HMAC is not such a system, and *will* produce collisions just like it was a random source, thereby not incurring this "thinning space" effect.