# Zero-Knowledgeness of Fiat-Shamir heuristic

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, fiat-shamir

I have read about the Fiat-Shamir heuristic for making an interactive proof of knowledge into a non-interactive proof of knowledge. If I apply this to zero-knowledge proof of knowledge, it seems to me that I would destroy the simulator and therefore the zero-knowledgeness.

Does the Fiat-Shamir heuristic destroy zero-knowledgeness?
If it does, it it possible to circumvent this?

[Link to Fiat-Shamir heuristic.](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~dmst/teaching/SS2012/Vorlesung/Fiat.Shamir.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [random-oracle model](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/879/what-is-the-random-oracle-model-and-why-is-it-controversial), it has been shown that the Fiat-Shamir transform preserves the soundness and zero-knowledge of *certain* families of zero-knowledge (proof of knowledge) protocols (e.g., [Sigma protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge#Sigma_protocols)) -- see [§5 in BR93,PS00,FKMV12]. Instantiating the random oracle with a concrete hash function is a much harder prospect, but there have been some recent works in this direction as well --- for example, the recent construction of NIZK from LWE relies on such an instantiation of the Fiat-Shamir transform [PS19].

P.S. Zero-knowledge is usually easy to show -- it is arguing soundness that usually causes problems in the non-interactive setting.

[BR93]: Bellare and Rogaway: [Random Oracles are Practical: A Paradigm for Designing Efficient Protocols](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/ro.pdf)
[FKMV12]: Faust et al. [On the Non-malleability of the Fiat-Shamir Transform](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/704)
[PS00]: Pointcheval and Stern: [Security Arguments for Digital Signatures and Blind Signatures](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/2000_joc.pdf)
[PS19]: Peikert and Sheihan [Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge for NP from (Plain) LWE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/158).