# What is the main difference between Unique signature and Verifiable Random Function?

Tags: signature, verifiable-random-function

The output of VRF contains two parts, the first is the output of the VRF hashing and the second is the proof of correctness. In a unique signature scheme, the signature also contains two parts which are similar to the VRF.

The previous works pointed out the VRF can be obtained via a unique signature, but in general, they have the same outputs, so I am confusing what are the main differences between them? Is there a generic framework of how to construct a VRF from the unique signature? Or we can say, once obtained a unique signature, then we can say it is a VRF?

Answer (score 6):

A signature scheme has the following two functions for a key pair $(k, K)$:

- $\sigma = \operatorname{Sign}_k(m)$
- $\mathit{valid?} = \operatorname{Verify}_K(m, \sigma)$

A VRF has slightly more:

- $(\sigma, x) = \operatorname{VRF}_k(m)$
- $\mathit{valid?} = \operatorname{Verify}_K(m, \sigma, x)$

***Without knowledge of the public key $K$ and the signature $\sigma$*, the VRF output $x$ appears to be an independent uniform random bit string for each distinct $m$.**  That is why it is a *verifiably* pseudorandom function: *except for verifiability*, it appears to have independent uniform random outputs.

In contrast, for example, RSA-based signatures typically have a per-key distribution that is distinctive enough to [deanonymize signers in practice](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/728) ([popular exposition](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2014/10/29/attack-of-week-unpicking-plaid/); actually this was RSA-based ciphertexts but the principle is the same).  While EdDSA signatures do not have a distinctive *per-key* distribution, they easily distinguished from uniform random bit strings because they encode $(R, s)$ where $R$ is a point on the curve (only about half of such bit strings will be so) and $s$ is an integer below the order of the curve (which is often substantially less than the number of bit strings of the same length).

If there is exactly one $\sigma$ for each $m$ under any particular public key $K$, then we can *devise* a VRF with the help of a uniform random function $H$ as follows:

- $\operatorname{VRF}_k(m) := (\sigma, H(\sigma))$, where $\sigma = \operatorname{Sign}_k(m)$
- $\operatorname{Verify}_K(m, \sigma, x) := (\operatorname{Verify}_K(m, \sigma) \mathrel{\text{and}} x \stackrel?= H(\sigma))$

Choosing, *e.g.*, $H = \operatorname{SHA-256}$ makes a practical VRF that is [secure against $H$-generic adversaries](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75610), or ‘secure in the [random oracle model](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68298)’, because without knowledge of the unique $\sigma$ for any particular $m$, $H(\sigma)$ is a uniform random bit string independent of anything else you can compute.

([More on signatures *vs.* VRFs with references](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50683).)